# Setting Y axis data order without changing source data

Tags: excel, charts, axis, flip

So im trying to make my scatter chart start from (in this case) 30 - 1 instead from 1 -30 [enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJtTk.jpg

so im trying to make the graph start at 30

what the graph is supposed to look like is if you were to rotate this image 180 degrees.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cIB.png

any help is much appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It would fit better at Super User

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Y-axis of your chart and select format axis. Under that, check 'values in reverse order' in Axis Option. Hope this is what you are looking for!